# count how many times a class appears in a page with codeception

Tags: codeception

I'm using Codeception to run acceptance tests and I need to count how many times a button with ".remove" class appears in one page. Such button is located inside a html table and the count depends on how many items are in the cart.
Below is the code I'm trying to use:

```
    $I->amOnPage("/cart/");
    $table = $I->grabTextFrom(".//*[@id='cart']/table");
    $rows = explode("<tr>", $table);
    $rcount = count($rows);
    while ($rcount >= 0) {
        $I->click(".remove");
        $rcount--;
    }
    $I->see("Your shopping cart is empty.");
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a bit late, but you should try $I->seeNumberOfElements as explained here:

http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#seeNumberOfElements

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrayProducts = $I->grabMultiple(XPATH_PRODUCTS_BOX);
        $sumProducts = count($arrayProducts);
        $I->comment("In category $selectCategory is total product: $sumProducts");
        $I->seeNumberOfElements(XPATH_PRODUCTS_BOX, $sumProducts);
        return $sumProducts;
```